# How can you unset entity view display component with config override?

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have an `entity view display` configuration where I would like to "unset" a component (one of the field). I implement the `ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface`
with the right service configuration.
Is there a way not just override a configuration array but completely remove one of it's key? (in this case one of the component).

I also found where the return value of this method (`loadOverrides`) is being processed and unfortunately the `NestedArray::merge` is used which gives a higher precedent to the original config. (which in the end won't let you to remove a key..)

Any ideas how to solve this? (this has to happen runtime.. the change mustn't be permanent like simply changing it on the UI and save)

Comment: You could use [hook_entity_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.6.x)

Comment: That's a good idea: will I be able still "save" the view display page without not the configuration change be part of the configuration export?

Comment: Or perhaps [`hook_entity_view_display_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_display_alter)?